# Web API Status Endpoint (GET and POST)

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, newrelic

We're using New Relic to monitor many of our web applications.

This gives us availability monitoring, which allows you to specify a particular endpoint in your application that can be "pinged" to make sure you application is "alive" - obviously quite useful, but there is a small catch.

I noticed that the ping request I get from New Relic is not always a `POST`, it is sometimes a `GET`, which results in my endpoint throwing a `405 HttpStatusMessage : Method not allowed`.

No problem - I figured I'd just configure my endpoint to respond to both :

```
[Route("status")]
public class StatusController : ApiController
{
    public IHttpActionResult Post()
    {
        return Ok();
    }

    public IHttpActionResult Get()
    {
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

Now granted, this does work, but seems like a lot of trouble for such a simple task.

I'm curious - is there a cleaner or better way of doing this, that I just haven't seen yet?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get your method to accept both POST and GET

```
// Route /status to this controller
[RoutePrefix("status")]
public class StatusController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet] // accept get
    [HttpPost] // accept post
    [Route("")] // route default request to this method.
    public IHttpActionResult Get()
    {
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The pingers will use a HEAD request by default unless a substring is used or a problem is detected.  In either of those two cases a GET request is issued.

Your solution looks pretty simple to me.

Comment: Ah - that makes more sense now, thanks for the clarification.